# How to run multiple applications on the same server in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want run more than one application on rails server so I user following command:
Command :

```
 rails s 3001
```

But it is not working

Comment: Use `rails s -p  3001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
rails s -p 3001
```

or

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001
```